# export all the data into excel sheet of a particular user who has logged using php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to export only those records which a particular  user has entered. For example: I have logged in by user id - user_test and i have few records which i have entered. for the same when the record is saved into the database my login name is also being saved along with the record. When i want to fetch and display the data of the particular user in session its working fine. but when i am using the same query for downloading the report i am not getting any error, the page is getting download with blank fields. Here is the code i am using for downloading the records in excel sheet.

```
<?php
include_once 'classes/admin-class.php';
$admin = new itg_admin();
$admin->_authenticate();
$ten = $_SESSION['admin_login'];
?>
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="kuidfc_project_monitoring";
    $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,$dbname); 

    $sql_data="SELECT * from user_daily_records WHERE users = '" . $admin->get_nicename() . "';";
    $result_data=$con->query($sql_data);
    $results=array();
    $filename = "Daily_Report.xls"; // File Name
    // Download file
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_data)) {
        if (!$flag) {
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @ RiggsFolly Yes, tried array_values still blank page.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I didnt see the second explode on first reading

Comment: Try exploding using comma's instead of tabs

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I think i am missing something in this query line, due to which i am getting an blank page.   "SELECT * from user_daily_records WHERE users = '" . $admin->get_nicename() . "';";

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Can you try `mysql_real_escape_string($admin->get_nicename())`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I added the code but still no error and a blank page is getting download.

Comment: Ok so does the `users` column hold the same info as you return from `$admin->get_nicename()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: yes the same info.

Comment: Instead of `$result_data=$con->query($sql_data);`, can you try `mysqli_query()`

Comment: @MilanChheda: Now i am getting error in the download page i.e. <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>C:\xamp\htdocs\kuidfc_project_monitoring\export.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br /> . When i changed to mysqli_query()

Comment: @MilanChheda: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>C:\xamp\htdocs\kuidfc_project_monitoring\export.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Comment: @MilanChheda: i fixed those 2 error , but still getting blank page on download

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT * FROM daily_progress_demo WHERE users = '" . $admin->get_nicename() . "'  ORDER BY startdate DESC ;"
```

I just sort by order in query it worked. Everything is coming perfect.